# Angular 2 animations - animate an image from one div to another

Tags: angular

Is there any way to animate an image from one div to another using angular 2 animations?

Example code:

```
    <div class="place1">PLACE 1
<img src="IMAGE"> <!--move that image to PLACE 2-->
</div>

    <div class="place2">PLACE 2</div>

place1 {
position:absolute;
top:50px;
right:50px;
}

place 2{
position:abvsolute;
bottom:50px;
left:50px;
}
```

Couldn't figure it out using the [Angular 2 animation docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS animations work by transitioning between states of selected CSS properties. In your div css definitions, the top right corner is positioned by `top`  and `right` properties, and the bottom left corner is by `bottom` and `left` properties. I don't know of any way how to transition from a `left` value to a `right` value, because these are two different ways of defining an element's position.

Luckily, you can use [CSS calculations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) and define both your divs' positions with the same properties, `top` and `left`:

```
.place1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: calc(100% - 128px);
}
.place2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 128px);
  left: 50px;
}
```

Now you can animate both the top and the left properties, and define the required transitions between them:

```
  animations: [
    trigger("move", [
      state("topRight", style({left: "calc(100% - 128px)", top: 0})),
      state("bottomLeft", style({left: 0, top: "calc(100% - 128px)"})),
      transition("topRight <=> bottomLeft", animate( "300ms ease-in ease-out" )),
    ])
```

And you bind this animation to your image, that should have the same initial position as your top right div:

```
<div class="moveMe" @move="state">
  <img src="your image URL">
</div>
```

Full working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/aVwOYM4Xw9vD75vMjGBc?p=preview