# Move div from one position to other with animation in ionic3-angular4 app

Tags: javascript, angular, css, ionic2, angular-animations

I am trying to do some animation in my mobile app developed in Ionic 3. I need to move a div from one position to another.

In the below code i need to move div with class "upper" after timeline-item tag according to count.

I am new to Angular 4 animations. Please help

[image]

Comment: Show us the code you have so far

Comment: @JulienRousé I was trying [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523016/angular-2-animations-animate-an-image-from-one-div-to-another)  so far. but my bad luck, its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The way animations work, is simply by switching classes of some elements and in the meanwhile adding some css properties.

You're not actually swapping nodes in the DOM. It's just that visually, some animation can "make it seem" like that.

If you want some quick animations, you can take a look at [AnimateCSS](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/) and add the classes it provides when you want the animation to fire.

You can actually swap elements in the DOM via JS, but this seems overkill for what you are trying to do.